# tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator does not load all the images present in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multilabel-classification

I am training a model to classify images into 10 different labels. To load data I'm using ImageDataGenerator.

```
tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator              

train_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/EuroSAT/Train/'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, batch_size=16, 
                  class_mode='categorical', target_size=(64, 64), 
                  subset ='training', shuffle = False)
```

But there are almost 3000 images in each category while `ImageDataGenerator` loads only 5443 images in total.

> Found 5827 images belonging to 10 classes.

What can I do to possibly go around?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any unsupported image format like `jfif`?

Comment: @Frightera yes I'm sure since ImageDataGenerator laods 23414 images from 10 different classes when I run the same code lacally in Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that you have image formats that are not supported or corrupted image files. This can happen often if for example you download images via google or bing. As I do this often I developed a function provided below that checks a directory that contains images held in sub directories (class directories if you are using the ImageDataGenerator(),flow_from_directory. It checks to see if the files are valid image files and have the extensions specified in a user defined list of proper extensions. The code is shown below. It is a bit lengthy because it does a lot of checking on inputs etc. Note if it detects a file with the extension jfif it renames it as jpg since they are the same format. The parameter convert_ext can be set to convert all the images to a new image format based on the extension  specified, for example 'bmp' If left as None the images retain their original format.

```
import os
import shutil
import cv2
def check_file_extension (source_dir, good_ext_list, delete=False, convert_ext=None): 
    # source_dir is the directory containing the class sub directories that hold the images
    # good_ext_list is a list of strings you specify as good extensions for the ImageDataGenerator
    # this list should be ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'png', 'tiff']
    # delete is a boolean, if set to True image files that have invalid extensions or are not valid
    # image files will be deleted.
    # the function return a list. If delete=False this is a list of all files that have invalid
    # extensions or are not valid image files
    # if convert_ext is set to other than None, it should be a string indicating the new image format
    # the files will be converted to, for example "jpg"
    processed_count=0 # will be total number of files found
    good_count=0 # will be total number of valid image files found
    bad_file_list=[]  # will be a list of all files processed that had invalid extensions
    removed_count=0  # will be the number of files deleted if delete is set to true
    class_list=os.listdir(source_dir)
    if len(class_list)==0:
        print('directory ', source_dir, ' is empty *** Program Terminating')
        return None
    print('{0:^20s}{1}{2:^17s}{1}{3:^14s}{1}{4:^15s}'.format('Class Directory',' ', 'Files Processed', 'Files Verified', 'Files Removed'))
    for klass in class_list:         
        class_path=os.path.join(source_dir, klass)
        if os.path.isdir(class_path)==False:# check if this is a directory if it is not print a warning
            print ('*** Warning *** there are files in ', source_dir, ' it should only contain sub directories' )
        else:
            class_file_count=0 # will be number of files found in the class directory            
            class_good_count=0 # will be the number of good files found in the class directory
            class_removed_count =0                                   
            f_list=os.listdir(class_path) # get a list of files in the class directory            
            for f in f_list:
                f_path=os.path.join(class_path,f)
                if os.path.isfile(f_path)==False: # check if it is a file if it is a directory print a warning
                    print ('*** Warning *** there is a directory in ', class_path, ' there should only be files there')
                else:
                    class_file_count +=1 #increment class file counter
                    index=f.rfind('.')
                    fname=f[:index]        
                    fext=f[index+1:].lower()
                    if fext not in good_ext_list and fext !='jfif':
                        if delete:
                            os.remove(f_path)
                            class_removed_count +=1 # increment removed file counter
                            
                        else:
                            bad_file_list.append(f_path) # don't delete but put the path in list of files with bad extensions
                            
                    else:
                        if fext =='jfif':   # if ext= jfif change it to jpg
                            fnew_path=os.path.join(class_path, fname + '.' + 'jpg')
                            shutil.copy(f_path,fnew_path )
                            os.remove(f_path)
                        else:
                            try:
                                img=cv2.imread(f_path)
                                shape=img.shape
                                if convert_ext !=None:
                                    fnew_path=os.path.join(class_path, fname + '.' + convert_ext)                                    
                                    cv2.imwrite(fnew_path,img)
                                    os.remove (f_path)
                                class_good_count +=1                                
                            except:
                                if delete:
                                    os.remove(f_path)
                                    class_removed_count +=1
                                else:
                                    bad_file_list.append(f_path)
            print('{0:^20s}{1}{2:^17s}{1}{3:^14s}{1}{4:^15s}'.format(klass,' ', str(class_file_count),str(class_good_count), str(class_removed_count)) )
            processed_count=processed_count + class_file_count
            good_count=good_count + class_good_count
            removed_count=removed_count+ class_removed_count 
    print('processed ', processed_count, ' files  ', good_count, 'files were verified  ', removed_count, ' files were removed')
       
    return bad_file_list
```

Below is an example of use

```
source_dir=r'c:\temp\people\storage'
good_ext_list=['jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'png']
new_ext='bmp'
bad_file_list=check_file_extension (source_dir, good_ext_list, delete=False,convert_ext=new_ext )
print (bad_file_list)
```

below is the typical output

```
 Class Directory     Files Processed  Files Verified  Files Removed 
       savory               20               20              0       
      unsavory              21               20              0       
processed  41  files   40 files were verified   0  files were removed
['c:\\temp\\people\\storage\\unsavory\\040.xyz']
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But there aren't any corrupted file as such. The same code i posted generates said 22 thousand photos when i run it in a jupyter notebook locally. Can you help out now?